# Why does `types.coroutine` not produce coroutines?

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine

For the following coroutine:

```py
import types

@types.coroutine
def f():
    yield 42
```

It appears that python still does not consider this a coroutine:

```py
>>> running_f = f()
>>> import inspect; inspect.iscoroutine(running_f)
False
>>> from collections.abc import Coroutine; isinstance(running_f, Coroutine)
False
```

Is there a test I can perform here that will let me observe that `types.coroutine` was used?

If `types.coroutine` didn't make `f()` a coroutine, then what did it do?

Comment: can you provide your output of python -V?

Comment: `sys.version` is `'3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'`

Comment: in python3.8 you can use the await/async syntax to write courutines https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines

Comment: That's true, but isn't really relevant to my question. I'm not asking _how_ to define coroutines, I'm asking _why_ `types.coroutine` appears not to work.

Comment: you can look at the code for types https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/types.py#L237 types.coroutines will work (it implements an __await__ method), but it's necessarily not an explicit instance of the abstact class Coroutine

Comment: In the code in my question, [this path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/types.py#L243-L266) is hit. `running_f.__await__()` is an `AttributeError`.